# mpdf deleted not needed Folders

Tags: mpdf

for a Project I´ve installed mpdf 6 via composer

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

It works great but the lib itself is ten times as big as my whole project. Are there any Files I can get rid of? For example when do I need iccprofiles Folder?  Or ttfonts (as I use a custom font in HTML)?

Thanks!

```
Base-Mac:mpdf base$ du -shc .??* *
 12K    .DS_Store
4,0K    .gitattributes
144K    CHANGELOG.txt
8,0K    CREDITS.txt
 20K    LICENSE.txt
8,0K    README.txt
1,2M    classes
656K    collations
4,0K    composer.json
8,0K    compress.php
 28K    config.php
8,0K    config_fonts-distr-without-OTL.php
 12K    config_fonts.php
 16K    config_lang2fonts.php
8,0K    config_script2lang.php
 88K    font
 28K    graph.php
4,0K    graph_cache
 40M    iccprofiles
1,5M    includes
 12K    lang2fonts.css
4,0K    mpdf.css
1,2M    mpdf.php
 52K    mpdfi
504K    patterns
4,0K    progbar.css
6,9M    qrcode
4,0K    tmp
536K    ttfontdata
 87M    ttfonts
140M    total
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is:

- create a minified version of mpdf:
  http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=406
- Edit config_fonts.php remove unneeded from $this->fontdata
- Remove unneded fonts from ttfonts
- delete iccprofiles as I do not use this

  …    14M   total

Comment: If you do not plan to generate QR codes, you can safely delete qrcode/data directory and save another 6+ MB

Comment: link is dead. I wish you had put the contents of the link

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo I think new link for creating lite version of mpdf is here: https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/reducing-memory-usage.html